# What rights user needs to run adamsync.exe under ws2008

Tags: windows

I'm logged as an administrator and I want to impersonate user using c# and then run adamsync.exe under this impersonate user context. Impersonated user  exists in the domain and belongs to domain group IIS_IUSRS. What rights should user have / into which groups should user belongs. I use ws2008. I got message The directory name is invalid.

When I use cmd, impersonate through run as and then run adamsync it is working.